# How this code is Working in C

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

```
void main()
{
 char c;
 clrscr();
 printf("Enter your name:\n");
 scanf("%s", c);
 printf("You entered your name as : \n")
 printf("%s",c);
 getch();
}

output//
Enter Your name:
sandeep
You entered your name as : 
sandeep
```

I am not getting how this single char variable 'c' stores a string when it is not a char array??

Comment: It is only working *by accident*. You are writing into memory you do not own. Not to mention you're invoking undefined behaviour by mismatching format specifiers and actual passed data.

Comment: If your name is long enough, you will reach a segment violation error

Comment: @DCoder: Dear friend, m also a programmer and I too know that this is a wrong program, & outcum shud not b like the way I showed. But I want to know why this code is giving above output each n everytime. And I have tried this code on different systems too.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't, really.

You're passing `c` (not the address of `c`) to `scanf`, so it's being promoted to `int`, then the value used as a pointer (because "%s" expects to write through a pointer to some memory). That gives undefined behavior. Apparently the value you happened to have in `c`, when promoted to `int` happened to come out to an address that you could write to without immediately causing obvious problems.

Pretty much the same thing happened when you passed it to `printf` as well, and since the addresses matched up, your output matched the input -- but there's no guarantee it will continue to do so if you run the same executable again, or if you compile with a different compiler, run on a different system, etc.

Comment: I believe there were just typos. If you correct the code and use &c instead of c, it behaves just as he says, but produces a segment violation if the name is too long (tested with gcc in ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? If it was you @Pablo, do you honestly think an answer qualifies as "not helpful" because it discusses what's there in the question rather than what you think may have been intended to be there? Is mind-reading necessary before an answer can be considered helpful?

Comment: I think your answer is useful, however I did the effort to try this code and found a way to make it work like the asker says it does. I downvoted because I don't think that the most voted answer should be the one that answers something I strongly believe was not the real question he intended. That's a problem I see with stackoverflow; once someone answers something and gets a few votes, the question stops getting any attention an the real question is never adressed.

Comment: Let me just say that I respect you, I can see you have contributed a lot to this community, and I agree that what should be answered is what was asked. I even considered opening a new question of my own with another code, and also tried to edit the question unsuccesfully. However the code he provided is invalid. It even lacks a semicolon! You have two options at hand: 1) assume the asker is stupid and can't tell the difference between working code and non working code or 2) he made some typos and the real question is hidden by them.

Comment: @Pablo: Yup I missed to type semicolon here, but in actual code there is semicolon after the printf() statement. But each time I run this code on different machine, like On my Pc and laptop, its working...

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I got your point, but please explain me that if this code is wrong then why this code is behaving in same way on different systems and giving right output i.e what I input is displayed as output... please xplain

Comment: @user1509612: One of the biggest problems with undefined behavior is that code can *seem* to work (and sometimes does for years at a time) even though it's clearly wrong. This can even be the case in code (e.g. Linux) that's *heavily* tested on thousands of machines for years, not just run a few times on a handful of machines.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong.  If it works, it works by accident, with the random value that happens to be in 'c' and the next 4 or 7 bytes (depending on your address size), pointing to a relatively harmless area of memory.  Maybe if you run it enough you'll generate a memory error when the junk in c and around c points to a less benign area of memory.

It should be char* c, initialized with a buffer or an array of characters.  C is a very, very simple language.  It should be throwing a warning during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it seems to work, scanf will write the string to an unallocated memory location. You shoul use an array or your programm is likely to crash someday.

Answer (score 0):

You have no compile time error because the prototype of scanf has "..." as the second argument. It means no type checking. Whether you get a run time error depends on your luck.